# Возвращаемое значение AJAX-запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пусть есть функция:

```
function sendRequest(Data){
  jQuery.ajax({
    'url':'http://phpscript.php'
    'data':Data,
    success: function(req) {
      //manipulation of req
    }
  })
}
```

Как правильно нужно реализовать код функции sendRequest() так, чтобы ответ ajax-запроса был значением (объектом, массивом, ...), возвращаемым функцией sendRequest()?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то не совсем понял, что Вам надо... Ответ ajax-запроса формируется не в текущей функции, а в серверном скрипте, к которому Вы стучитель по параметру 'url'. И если хотите, что бы даныне были массивом/объектом - возвращайте данные этим скриптом в формате json. Т.о. ajax-функция будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://phpscript.php',
    data: Data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(req) {
        //manipulation of req
    }
});
```

По адресу http://phpscript.php - Ваш скрипт-обработчик запроса.

Вообще читаните [это](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-ajax/) (на русском) и вот [это](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (офф. документация).

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы функция sendRequest возвращала результат ajax-запроса.
Чтоб было что-то типа этого, но так не работает.

function sendRequest(Data){
  jQuery.ajax({
    'url':'http://phpscript.php'
    'data':Data,
    success: function(req) {
      return req;//так 
    }
  })
}

Comment: Вам, видимо, нужен синхронный запрос. Посмотрите документацию №2, ссылку на которую дал @metazet, параметр async (обратите внимание на побочные эффекты). А внутри функции, которая вызывается "on success", присвойте значение `req` переменной, объявленной внутри `sendRequest`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Синхронный запрос это решение.
А можно ли сделать тоже самое, но с асинхронным запросом?

Comment: Хм, ну можно, например, составить конструкцию из `setInterval` и проверять переменную, значение которой присваивается `sendRequest`. Мне кажется, впрочем, что это скорее всего лишнее и можно обойтись действиями в callback-функции "on success".